# Calculate excel SUM of a column for days on each week

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet with two columns:

- A - contain the days of the week (Mon, Twe, Wed, Thu, Fri - maybe rarely even Sat and Sun)
- B - contain a number

The records may contain not a fixed amount of records for each day, so for example `Mon` can appear in 3 consecutive rows, while `Tue` only once. So for a week we have more records than the days in one week. Also the days of the week in column `A` are sorted.

What I want is the sum of those number based when week changes.
By change of the week it mean when we have on first record `Fri` and in the next `Mon` or `Thu` and `Mon`.

How can I write a formula in `C` column that it shows the result in the last day of each week?

[image: Sample column data]

Comment: So really the trigger is when the cell below = **Mon** but current cell not = **Mon**?

Comment: Is the first day of data always a Monday?  For example, could you ever run into a situation where one week had data for just Monday and Tuesday, and the following week's first entry was for Wed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following formula in `C2`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(A3),SUM(B$2:B2)-SUM(C$1:C1),IF(MATCH(A2,{"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"},)>MATCH(A3,{"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"},),SUM(B$2:B2)-SUM(C$1:C1),"")),"")
```

And populate down

Comment: This is almost what I want, but it doesn't produce the result for the last week. Should I add a dummy record at the end or can it be modified to get the sum for the last week?

Comment: See my edited formula

Comment: A little bit complicated but it does the work. Thank you!